# Opera and redirect issues

Tags: php, redirect, opera

Has anyone seen or heard of Opera having redirect issues? I have a PHP script that POSTs back to itself, sets up some variables and then redirects to another page. This fails on a Linux box but works with no issues on Windows.

**EDIT:**

I also need to mention that redirect works well and as expected in Chrome, FF and IE.
Redirect works in ALL browsers, Opera included if I'm on a windows machine. When I move my code to my Linux server, redirect breaks in Opera.

*Why does everything work on Windows and not in Linux? How does the browser know the difference? I honestly don't even know where to begin looking.*

Comment: No,I haven't (even as a long-time user of Opera since v.6).Please edit your question; adding these points may get you better answers:1.What version of the software is giving you trouble ("an Opera on a Linux" could mean many things)?1b.What are the differences in configuration between the Linux and Windows Operas? 2. What have you tried so far? 3. What results did you get? 4. How did that differ from the results you were expecting? Note also that Opera has the 10.60 stable branch,and the 10.7x experimental branch, which "may have severe known issues,including crashes and data loss situations."

Comment: This is a pretty specific question that deals with a reported browser bug. I'm certain that anyone having had experience with Opera and PHP will know exactly what I'm up against. I'm looking for a workaround.

Comment: How do you redirect after the form post?

Comment: From Googling... "you can check "Enable automatic redirection" in Opera's network preferences"

Comment: @jim: No, *this* is a pretty vague question. If you add detail, then it *could* be specific enough for us to help you. If you only say "it won't redirect for me", the most specific response you can get is "well that's a pity". Browser versions, OS versions, page doctype, all this may be necessary to uncover the root of the problem. If it's a reported browser bug, can you link to the bug report?

Comment: @Jim: please look at least at points 3 & 4 raised by Piskvor.  For anyone to really be able to help you we would need to know how it is not working on Linux.  Is everything happening but the server variables aren't set up, or is it not redirecting to the page you expect?   You just haven't said how it's "not working".  Also what leads you to believe the issue is specific to either PHP and/or Opera on Linux.  Is FF or Chrome on same linux box working?

Comment: Piskvor, please get lost if you're looking for a fight, I'm sorry but I'm a bit busy here trying to solve something.

Comment: @scunliffe: Good point, didn't think of that - esp. as it's been enabled by default since forever (sometime during version 6 I believe, which was many years ago). If the OP disabled that, it may help.

Comment: @scunliffe, Thank you. I'm going there now. I hope this does it.

Comment: @Gumbo, I redirect twice; once after the POST and then once again.

Comment: @jim: I'm not looking for a fight, and I'm sorry if I came across that way. I'm looking for additional data to help troubleshoot the problem. The question, as it stands now, does not have enough information to solve the issue. I understand you need to solve the problem ASAP, but we can't help you unless you provide more info. It's not that we wouldn't *want* to help you, but that we *can* not, as without more data, we're only guessing.

Comment: @jim: *How* do you redirect after the form post?

Comment: @Piskvor, No offense taken. Thanks for re explaining yourself :) The reason that I haven't gone into any real depth is because I'm afraid that before long, we will be posting code and nothing will get resolved. But, I'm willing to cooperate anyway.

Comment: @Gumbo, after the form is posted, I use header() to push the user to another location in the same page where I am setting a couple of session vars. After the session vars are set, that I header() to a final location in the same page.

Comment: @Gumbo, I also have to mention that the PHP header function works as expected in FF, Chrome as well as IE

Comment: @jim: Ok, great. Could you give us some more info then? You know, "because I'm afraid that before long, we will be posting code and nothing will get resolved" - what did we get resolved by arguing back and forth for half an hour about "do you *really REALLY* need to know my browser version?"

Comment: lol.. OK, you win Piskvor, I'm willing to play because this issue is REALLY bothering me now. I've posted what I know so far above in my original post.

Comment: @jim: Is it really that hard to give us more information? Information on what Opera version you’re using and on how exactly the redirection is actually implemented?

Comment: Gumbo, please forgive me if I sound rash here but it makes absolutely no sense, whatsoever, to talk about browser version when Opera works just dandy on my local doze box. Can you please tell me why you think that knowing the browser version will help to localize this issue? Again, I apologize if I sound harsh, but I'm just being logical. Please explain.

Comment: Just for the record, I'm using Opera Version
10.10

Comment: @jim: I'm not trying to win, I'm trying to get some more data (because, y'know, some bugs are actually *fixed* from one version to another, and thus a bug that appears in one version doesn't appear in another, and thus the behavior is different). Apparently, I have failed in that. I'm sorry that you're having problems and that I can not help you. I hope you will find someone who's willing to beg you for a description of the problem, and I wish you the best of luck to get the problem resolved. Goodbye.

Comment: @jim - we need some clarification. Is it correct that the redirection only fails (and only in Opera (on any platform)) when you move your application server from Windows to Linux?  If so, I'm wondering if you have paths defined with `"this\then\that"` vs. `"this/then/that"` ? If so, when you place these in your code, IE & Firefox might be auto-correcting the paths for you, whereas Opera might not be.  Can you post the actual PHP code you are using to do the redirection?

Comment: @jim: Not every Opera version is the same. Some versions have bugs that are fixed in later versions and some versions have features that previous versions didn’t had. Knowing what version you’re actually using might help to find the cause of this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Saw this sometimes with Konqueror a few years ago - I tend to avoid PRG as it often causes more problems than it solves (as evidenced here) but had a similar problem where more than one consecutive redirect (PRGRG - OMG!) failed.

> When I move my code to my Linux server, redirect breaks in Opera.

But that sounds like something completely different. I could understand if it broke everywhere - that'd point to a text conversion problem causing output to the body of the page before the header() cal (and hence the header call would fail). I suggest you look at a wiretap of the requests/responses for the 2 servers and see if you can see a difference.

Comment: For example use Microsoft Fiddler HTTP debugger from http://www.fiddler2.com/ to see what headers are sent, then check if they differ when you run this locally and when it is run on the server..